# How to generate a java bean class from an interface in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, interface, intellij-idea, javabeans

So, there already is a way to generate an implementation of a class in IntelliJ (v11), but it is rather simple.

It will create a class with all the methods necessary to satisfy the interface.  These methods are empty and return null where appropriate.

What I am looking for is a plugin or something that will generate beans from a interface.  If the generator sees a method getXXXX or setXXX (or isXXX) in the interface, it will create a member of that type and get or return that member, respectively in the implemented class.

Comment: of course I probably could have scripted one in the time it took to type this post.  But it would be nice to find a plugin that does this.

Comment: Why just Idea? I want this for Eclipse too!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you can do is create a new class that implements the interface, then tell IntelliJ to implement all the methods.  From that point, it's up to you to fill in the meat of the methods.  There's no magic that I know of.

Comment: Accepted and voted up three and a half years later.  Still good, I guess.